# Set rownames row number

Tags: r

I have a very large matrix M and I would like the name of each row of the matrix to be `Person i`, where `i` is the row number. I basically want the logical equivalent of the following:

```
names <- vector()
for(i in 1:numberofrows) {
    names[i] <- ("Person " , i)
}
rownames(M) <- names
```

I'm new to R so the above might not make complete syntactical sense but I'm just trying to convey the logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rownames(M) <- paste("Person",seq(nrow(M)))
```